# How get copy of objects from oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i, release-management, oracleforms

I have plan to do a release for our product. we are using Oracle forms to develop our software.

So I have two type of object for release

1. Front-end => Oracle forms
2. Back-end => Oracle Database Program (Procedure, function and Package)

One of the important part of release is we need to have a back up so if any thing happen we can use the older version.

By the way, for front end object I will use some batch file to create a back up for my front end objects but for Back-end object I dont know how I can get a copy of function, procedure or package(spec & body) automatically.

Any idea how I can do it automatically? please advice me.
we are using oracle 10g & 9i

Comment: Select fields from ALL_SOURCE where Name = ObjectName will work on anything but a trigger.  Select fields from All_Triggers will work on triggers.  Store those values into a "BACKUP" table before you overright you with your new objects and your done.  Though I believe DBA's have better approaches.

Comment: Aren't you using a source control tool to manage your code?

Comment: @APC: We are using PVCS for keep track of our version but I want immediate action to role back everything in customer side. In my company sometimes developer apply some package or function during the webbex so sometimes customer production is not same as our pvcs.(1 or 2 case). Do u have any experience in release? can u advice me?

Comment: @xQbert: Thanks I will follow up with our DBA team.

Comment: Ask you DBA team to export the schema and you'll have a copy of all youe objects and the data in them

Comment: @xQbert: our DBA also looking for a solution make it automate. So they couldnt help me. would you explain more?

Comment: Oracle has system tables which contain the DDL for every object.  My suggestion is to [use ddl triggers](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_dbazine_sys_trigs.htm) to backup DDL beofre it gets changed automatically; I don't know about the rollback you mentioned in a comment though...  IF you are simply looking to backup the source, triggers looking at DDL changes, or based on the actual system tables containing the source are a good place to start.  This is NOT an exact answer; just a comment to consider. (surprised DBA's didn't know about this though)

Comment: I found a useful query to help me :)   SELECT TEXT FROM USER_SOURCE WHERE NAME LIKE '<YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME>'

Comment: NOw I have a problem I can find a package and a package body but how I can split them? they will come in one file :(

Comment: @rima : you need to setup a better code promotion system (not just dev sandbox but test env that mirrors prod setup) and have devs submit through your source control (IT pulls from there and applies to test env).  When u say developer applies changes directly to prod it is asking from problems, which is why you are looking to automatically revert back to some previous version.  Better practices should be your goal imo.

Comment: I hear Oracle databases can be backed up and restored later.

Comment: @rima, it doesn't matter whether a package spec and body is in the same file as long as the specification is first. If you're going to go down this massively over-convoluted route then I'd recommend `dbms_metadata`, but you should listen to everyone else and have proper version control and backups.

Comment: @Ben: we have but as u know when we release a solution to customer fist they apply in UAT env and then their QA test it. Then if was okay solution will move to production. there is so many challenge for send a release ...

Answer (score 2):

> "In my company sometimes developer apply some package or function
>   during the webbex so sometimes customer production is not same as our
>   pvcs."

So what is the point of storing code in a repository?  What is the point of testing a configuration?  What is the point of release management?

If these cowboy developers who muck around with your customers' production environments are your staff you need to discipline them.  Enforce process to guarantee that only certified configurations are deployed.  If emergency tweaks are required these should be retrofitted into the official build.

If these developers actually work for the customer, then I suppose you cannot stop them.  But you don't have to support them, and you don't have to be responsible for their changes.  (unless the sales contract says you have to, which wouldn't surprise me.)

Comment: I agree with you, but believe me they dont know about value of configuration management in company, that's why sometimes these kind of problem will happen.by the way we try to identify them and stop them... Our management is not clear about how to punish them... how other company punish this kind of developers?

Comment: @rima - sorry but advising you on company disciplinary procedures is *way* off topic.  What I will suggest is this: if your co-workers don't understand the importance of due process and your managers don't now how to enforce policy properly then perhaps it's time to look for a new employer?

Comment: I would like, but really in malaysia I couldnt find any CM job :( just in US! at the moment working here is so valuable for me :) if you have any friend please introduce to me :)

Answer (score 1):

(Apologies for the code-blob).

Here's some code I've used to handle issues like this:

```
PROCEDURE DUMP_CLOB(aCLOB        IN CLOB,
                    hOutput_file IN UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) IS
  nCLOB_length       NUMBER;
  nCLOB_offset       NUMBER := 1;
  nMax_chunk_size    NUMBER := 32767;
  strChunk           VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  nCLOB_length := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(aCLOB);

  WHILE nCLOB_offset <= nCLOB_length LOOP
    strChunk := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(aCLOB, nMax_chunk_size, nCLOB_offset);

    UTL_FILE.PUT(hOutput_file, strChunk);

    nCLOB_offset := nCLOB_offset + LENGTH(strChunk);
  END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(hOutput_file, ';');
END DUMP_CLOB;

PROCEDURE DUMP_PRIVS(strOwner        IN  VARCHAR2,
                     strObject_name  IN  VARCHAR2,
                     hOutput_file    IN  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) IS
BEGIN
  FOR pRow IN (SELECT *
                 FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS p
                 WHERE p.OWNER = strOwner AND
                       p.TABLE_NAME = strObject_name)
  LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(hOutput_file, 'GRANT ' || pRow.PRIVILEGE || ' ON ' ||
                                    strOwner || '.' || strObject_name ||
                                    ' TO ' || pRow.GRANTEE || ';');
  END LOOP;
END DUMP_PRIVS;

PROCEDURE DUMP_OBJECT(strOwner        IN  VARCHAR2,
                      strObject_name  IN  VARCHAR2,
                      hOutput_file    IN  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE)
IS
  clobDDL              CLOB;
  strCurr_object_name  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR rowObject IN (SELECT *
                      FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS o
                      WHERE o.OWNER = strOwner AND
                            o.OBJECT_NAME = strObject_name AND
                            o.OBJECT_TYPE <> 'TABLE PARTITION')
  LOOP
    strCurr_object_name := NVL(rowObject.SUBOBJECT_NAME, rowObject.OBJECT_NAME);

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(hOutput_file, '-- DDL for ' || LOWER(rowObject.OBJECT_TYPE) || ' ' ||
                                    strOwner || '.' || strCurr_object_name);

    SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(rowObject.OBJECT_TYPE, strCurr_object_name, strOwner) AS DDL
      INTO clobDDL
      FROM DUAL;

    DUMP_CLOB(clobDDL, hOutput_file);

    DUMP_PRIVS(strOwner, strCurr_object_name, hOutput_file);

    IF rowObject.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
      -- Indexes

      FOR aRow IN (SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', i.INDEX_NAME, i.OWNER) AS clobIndex
                     FROM DBA_INDEXES I
                     WHERE I.TABLE_OWNER = strOwner AND
                           I.TABLE_NAME = strCurr_object_name)
      LOOP
        DUMP_CLOB(aRow.clobIndex, hOutput_file);
      END LOOP;  -- Indexes
    END IF;

    IF rowObject.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'VIEW') THEN
      -- Triggers

      FOR aRow IN (SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TRIGGER', t.TRIGGER_NAME, t.OWNER) AS clobTrigger
                     FROM DBA_TRIGGERS t
                     WHERE TABLE_OWNER = strOwner AND
                     TABLE_NAME = strCurr_object_name)
      LOOP
        DUMP_CLOB(aRow.clobTrigger, hOutput_file);
      END LOOP;  -- Triggers
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END DUMP_OBJECT;


PROCEDURE DUMP_OBJECT(strOwner           IN  VARCHAR2,
                      strObject_name     IN  VARCHAR2,
                      strDirectory_name  IN  VARCHAR2,
                      strFilename        IN  VARCHAR2,
                      strOpen_mode       IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'w')
IS
  hOutput_file  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  hOutput_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location  => strDirectory_name,
                                 filename  => strFilename,
                                 open_mode => strOpen_mode);
  DUMP_OBJECT(strOwner, strObject_name, hOutput_file);
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(hOutput_file);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(hOutput_file);
    RAISE;
END DUMP_OBJECT;
```

I suggest putting these procedures into a package.  Call DUMP_OBJECT for the things you want dumped.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: would u tell me what should I put for str owner and directory_name and what is differences object_name and filename?

Comment: strOwner is the schema in which the object you want to dump exists.  strDirectory_name is the name of a directory in your filesystem which is accessible through UTL_FILE where you want to create your file.  strFilename is the name of the file you want to create into which the DDL will be written.